# Ruby and Nokogiri parsing table?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

This is my HTML:

```
<tbody><tr><th>SHOES</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Shoe 1 <br>shoe 2<br> shoe3 <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is my code:

```
nodes = page.css("tr").select do |el|
  el.css('th').text =~ /SHOES/
end

nodes.each do |value|
  puts value.css("td").text
end
```

I wish to get the values `shoe 1`, `shoe 2` and `shoe 3`, but there is no output. I suspect there is an extra `<tr></tr>` in between `<tr><th>SHOES</th></tr>`. Or are the `<br>`  the culprit?

There are other structures like:

```
<tr>
  <th>SHOES</th>
  <td>NBA</td>
</tr>
```

and I got the desired output `"NBA"`.

What did I do wrong?

I have two kinds of structures:

```
Name1: value
Name1: value2
```

The above would give:

```
<tr>
<th>Name1</th>
<td>Value</td>
</tr>
```

but sometimes it's:

```
Name:
value
value2
value3
```

So the HTML is:

```
<tbody><tr><th>Name</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>value<br>value2<br> ....</td>
```

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205082/extracting-between-br-tags-with-nokogiri) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058922/using-nokogiri-to-split-content-on-br-tags)

Comment: Because in your second `tr`, there is no `th`. `el.css('th').text =~ /SHOES/` selecting `tr`(s) only those which has `th` ta`g and a text pattern `SHOES`.

Comment: so should i change my code to `nodes = page.css("th").select do |el|` instead? how should i get the `th` value `SHOES` then?

Comment: @dorothy Why you need `th` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, i need to search specific `th` values, then output their `td` values. Since some of the html i got has different structure, i guess getting `th` is better than `tr` because every `th` comes with a corresponding `td`.

Comment: @dorothy `    <td>
    Shoe 1 <br>shoe 2<br> shoe3 <br>
    </td>` not associated with `th`.. So do you want this `td` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, yes. I suppose changing to `nodes = page.css("th").select do |el|` instead of `nodes = page.css("tr").select do |el|` should be ok?

Comment: @dorothy with your updated html, tell me what are the text you want to grab ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML, tables are composed by rows. When you iterate by those rows, only one of them is the header. Although logically you see a relation between the body rows and the header ones, for HTML (and therefore for Nokogiri) there's none.

If what you want, is to get every value of the cells that have a specific header, what you can do is count the specific column, and then get the values from there.

Using this HTML as source

```
html = '<tbody><tr><th>HATS</th><th>SHOES</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      hat 1 <br>hat 2<br> hat3 <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      Shoe 1 <br>shoe 2<br> shoe3 <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>'
```

We then follow to get the position of the right , in the first row of the table

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

shoes_position = page.css("tr")[0].css('th').find_index do |el|
  el.text =~ /SHOES/
end
```

And with that, we find the s in that position in every other row, and get the text from that

```
shoes_tds = page.css('tr').map {|row| row.css('td')[shoes_position] }.compact
shoes_names = shoes_tds.map { |td| td.text }
```

I use a compact to remove the nil values, as the first row (the one with the headers) will not have a td, thus returning nil

Comment: thanks. although i have solved my problem using `.next_element`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get there with css:

```
td = doc.at('tr:has(th[text()=SHOES]) + tr td')
td.children.map{|x| x.text.strip}.reject(&:empty?)
#=> ["Shoe 1", "shoe 2", "shoe3"]
```

but maybe mixing it up with xpath is better:

```
td.search('./text()').map{|x| x.text.strip}
#=> ["Shoe 1", "shoe 2", "shoe3"]
```